# How does electrolyte impurities affect the voltage in a voltaic cell?

Tags: electrochemistry

I'm currently doing my FYP assignment on electrochemistry (predominantly on voltaic cells). As I was conducting my research I managed to come off with this topic as stated in the title, however, I am not too keen with the term electrolyte impurities. So, my question is what are electrolyte impurities? Can anyone give a brief explanation with an example? And how does the presence of this impurities affect the voltage in a voltaic cell?

Comment: How can we answer this question? Every impurities can interfere whit everything. The words probably mean impurities that can be in the electrolyte for EC (so they can be with the salt or with the solvent) or some electrolyte in the measured devices etc.

Comment: Yes! that's what I meant, sorry if I word it wrongly. What would be the impurities in an electrolyte for EC? An example would be great.